# Google Map Events from JS Library

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've been following a YouTube tutorial on Google Maps and I've come across a problem that I can't resolve. This is likely an easy problem to solve but I am new at using both HTML and JavaScript and can't put my finger on it.

[YouTube Tutorial - Custom Interactive Maps with the Google Maps API 08 Marker Events](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLnzmihIg-Q&index=6&list=PLgGbWId6zgaXFR4SW_3qJ55cxmEqRNIzx#t=242.459574)

How do I call a map event using the _on function from the below JS library (as opposed to a marker event).

```
_on: function(opts) {
    var self = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(opts.obj, opts.event, function(e) {
      opts.callback.call(self, e);
    });
  },
  addMarker: function(opts) {
    var marker;
    opts.position = {
      lat: opts.lat,
      lng: opts.lng
    }
    marker = this._createMarker(opts);
    if (opts.event) {
      this._on({
        obj: marker,
        event: opts.event.name,
        callback: opts.event.callback
      });
    }
  },
  _createMarker: function(opts) {
    opts.map = this.gMap;
    return new google.maps.Marker(opts);
  }
```

After tutorial 07 I was able to call a map event because the _on function was as follows:

```
_on: function(event, callback) {
  var self = this;
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.gMap, event, function(e) {
    callback.call(self, e);
  });
}
```

I was able to call the map event function from my Script.js file with the following code after tutorial 7:

```
map._on('rightclick', function() {
  alert('Right Click');
});
```

However, now that my _on function has been modified in tutorial 8, I can't seem to figure out how I can call the map event function as the input variable has changed to opts.

I attempted the following but it's not working properly:

```
map._on({
  obj: map,
  event: 'dragend',
  callback: function() {
    alert('I was dragged');
  }
});
```

Could somebody please let me know what I am doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
map._on({
  obj: map.gMap,
  event: 'dragend',
  callback: function() {
    alert('I was dragged');
  }
});
```

The error lied in the fact my object needed to be declared as 'map.gMap' as opposed to just using 'map'.